# How can I store the scanner input integers in Java so I can print the sum of a list of input integer numbers?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing the University of Helsinki's Java MOOC and there is an exercise that asks me to create a program that lets you input as much numbers as you want, but when you input a '0' it prints the sum of all the previously input numbers and ends the program. I can't figure out how to 'store' the input numbers for calculating the sum of them when you input a '0'. The program works but inputting '0' prints '0'. This is how my code looks:

```
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input a number.");

    while (true) {
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Input another number.");

            if (number == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + number);
                break;
            }
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid number.");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I calculate the sum of all the input numbers?

Comment: You can store it in a list? The sum to elements in the list

Comment: Why do you need to "store" them, and not do `total += number` (e.g.)?

Comment: As for why your current version does not work, think about what happens to your `number` variable every time it loops. You're throwing away your previous loop value of the `number` by not maintaining a separate reference to the stored value and are overriding the value your declaration is looking at. You would need to store your variable outside your loop if you want it to remain after every new loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a counter and make smth like this, you don't need to save all numbers:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Input a number.");

    while (true) {
      try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        sum += number;
        System.out.println("Input another number.");

        if (number == 0) {
          System.out.println(sum);
          break;
        }
      }

      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please input a valid number.");
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In line with my comment above:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int number = -1;

        while (number != 0) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Input a number (0 to quit): ");
                number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                sum += number;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Please input a valid number.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total:" + sum);
    }
```